# how to write the value to each matrix index

Tags: c#

For example, I have set up a formula to find my `Xnew[k+1], Ynew[k+1] and Anew[k+1]`.

How do I pass the value to a 3 by 1 matrix if I want my

- index 1,1 be `Xnew[k+1]`,
- index 1,2 be `Ynew[k+1]`,
- index 1,3 be `Anew[k+1]`.

Here's what I got so far.

```
for (k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{
    Xnew[k+1] = cX + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Cos(cA);
    Ynew[k+1] = cY + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Sin(cA);
    Anew[k+1] = cA + (T * MPCW[k]);

    double[,] qK = new double[3, 1];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            qK[i, j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that 3x1 2d array in C# does not have index [1,1]... Overall it is unclear what exactly is a problem with assigning values to elements of 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suposing `Xnew[k+1]`, `Ynew[k+1]` and `Anew[k+1]` are doubles:

```
for ( k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
    Xnew[k + 1] = cX + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Cos(cA);
    Ynew[k + 1] = cY + (T * MPCV[k]) * Math.Sin(cA);
    Anew[k + 1] = cA + (T * MPCW[k]);

    double[,] qk = { { Xnew[k + 1] ,  Ynew[k + 1] ,  Anew[k + 1] } };
}
```

This will make you a 1x3 matrix (arrays start in 0) with:

- `qk[0,0]` = `Xnew[k+1]`
- `qk[0,1]` = `Ynew[k+1]`
- `qk[0,2]` = `Anew[k+1]`

But if you want a 3x1 matrix use instead.

```
 double[,] qk = { { Xnew[k + 1] },  {Ynew[k + 1] },  {Anew[k + 1] } };
```

That will give you:

- `qk[0,0]` = `Xnew[k+1]`
- `qk[1,0]` = `Ynew[k+1]`
- `qk[2,0]` = `Anew[k+1]`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! i have such a hard time thinking for this and realize its my silly mistake in declaring the wrong matrix

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark this as the best answer if it's ok for you =)